# Проверка активности QRadioButton

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, radiobutton, qbuttongroup

Есть две QRadioButton. В зависимости от того, какая активна, при нажатии обычной кнопки, нужно вписывать в лейблы результат той или иной функции, вот только не знаю как проверять состояние радиокнопки.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from smthg import parse_student, parse_teacher


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    widgets_stylesheet = "background: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n""font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";"

    def __init__(self):
        # Базовые настройки
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(1920, 1080)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 147, 84)")

        self.CentralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.CentralWidget.setObjectName("CentralWidget")

        ''' Контейнеры с расписанием '''
        self.MondaySheduleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.MondaySheduleLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 350, 341, 701))
        self.MondaySheduleLabel.setText("")
        self.MondaySheduleLabel.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)

        self.TuesdaySheduleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.TuesdaySheduleLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 350, 341, 701))
        self.TuesdaySheduleLabel.setText("")
        self.TuesdaySheduleLabelself.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)

        self.WednesdaySheduleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.WednesdaySheduleLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 350, 341, 701))
        self.WednesdaySheduleLabel.setText("")
        self.WednesdaySheduleLabel.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)

        self.ThursdaySheduleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.ThursdaySheduleLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1160, 350, 341, 701))
        self.ThursdaySheduleLabel.setText("")
        self.ThursdaySheduleLabel.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)

        self.FridaySheduleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.FridaySheduleLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1540, 350, 341, 701))
        self.FridaySheduleLabel.setText("")
        self.FridaySheduleLabel.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)

        ''' Радиокнопки '''
        self.StudentRadioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.CentralWidget)
        self.StudentRadioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 40, 271, 81))
        self.StudentRadioButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(271, 1))
        self.StudentRadioButton.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)

        self.TeacherRadioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.CentralWidget)
        self.TeacherRadioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 170, 271, 81))
        self.TeacherRadioButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(271, 0))
        self.TeacherRadioButton.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)

        ''' Надписи '''
        self.MondayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.MondayLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 290, 201, 51))

        self.TuesdayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.TuesdayLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 290, 201, 51))

        self.WednesdayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.WednesdayLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 290, 201, 51))

        self.ThursdayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.ThursdayLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1230, 290, 201, 51))
        self.ThursdayLabel.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)

        self.FridayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.FridayLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1610, 290, 201, 51))
        self.FridayLabel.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)

        self.ClassLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.ClassLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(970, 40, 251, 81))
        self.ClassLabel.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)
        self.ClassLabel.setObjectName("ClassLabel")

        self.TeacherLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.TeacherLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 170, 431, 81))
        self.TeacherLabel.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)
        self.TeacherLabel.setObjectName("TeacherLabel")

        ''' Окна ввода '''
        self.ClassValueLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.CentralWidget)
        self.ClassValueLineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1260, 40, 81, 81))
        self.ClassValueLineEdit.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)
        self.ClassValueLineEdit.setText("")
        self.ClassValueLineEdit.setObjectName("ClassValueLineEdit")

        self.TeacherValueLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.CentralWidget)
        self.TeacherValueLineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1260, 170, 231, 81))
        self.TeacherValueLineEdit.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)
        self.TeacherValueLineEdit.setText("123")
        self.TeacherValueLineEdit.setObjectName("TeacherValueLineEdit")

        ''' Иконка школы'''
        self.SchoolIconLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.CentralWidget)
        self.SchoolIconLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 191, 191))
        self.SchoolIconLabel.setStyleSheet("background: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.SchoolIconLabel.setText("")
        self.SchoolIconLabel.setObjectName("SchoolIconLabel")

        # Кнопка
        self.Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.CentralWidget)
        self.Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1670, 100, 91, 91))
        self.Button.setStyleSheet(self.widgets_stylesheet)
        self.Button.setObjectName("Button")
        self.Button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.CentralWidget)

        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslate_ui()

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslate_ui(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Менеджер расписаний"))
        self.StudentRadioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Ученик"))
        self.TeacherRadioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Учитель"))
        self.MondayLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "  Понедельник"))
        self.TuesdayLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "      Вторник"))
        self.WednesdayLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "        Среда"))
        self.ThursdayLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "     Четверг"))
        self.FridayLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "      Пятница"))
        self.ClassLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Введите класс: "))
        self.TeacherLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Введите фамилию учителя:"))
        self.Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОК"))

    def button_clicked(self):
        """ Функция нажатия кнопки """
        # Проверка состояния радиокнопки:
        pass
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я много чего поменял в вашем коде и добавил нужную вам проверку. Постарайтесь понять каждое изменение, если что-то будет не понятно - спросите.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# ??? from smthg import parse_student, parse_teacher


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        # Контейнеры с расписанием
        self.mondaySheduleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(minimumWidth=200)
        self.tuesdaySheduleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(minimumWidth=200)
        self.wednesdaySheduleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(minimumWidth=200)
        self.thursdaySheduleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(minimumWidth=200)
        self.fridaySheduleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(minimumWidth=200)

        # Радиокнопки
        self.studentRadioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('Ученик')
        self.teacherRadioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('Учитель')

        # Надписи
        self.mondayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Понедельник', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tuesdayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Вторник', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.wednesdayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Среда', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.thursdayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Четверг', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.fridayLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            'Пятница', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, maximumHeight=50)

        # Окна ввода
        self.classValueLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText="Введите класс")
        self.teacherValueLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText="Введите фамилию учителя")

        # Иконка школы
        self.schoolIconLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.schoolIconLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(200, 200))

        # Кнопка
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('ОК')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

        self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.studentRadioButton)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.teacherRadioButton)    
        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)
        
        self.selected_button = None
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.schoolIconLabel, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.studentRadioButton, 0, 1, 1, 1)        
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.teacherRadioButton, 1, 1, 1, 1)        
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.classValueLineEdit, 0, 2, 1, 2)        
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.teacherValueLineEdit, 1, 2, 1, 2) 
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button, 0, 4, 2, 1)  

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.mondayLabel, 3, 0, 1, 1)  
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tuesdayLabel, 3, 1, 1, 1)  
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.wednesdayLabel, 3, 2, 1, 1)  
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.thursdayLabel, 3, 3, 1, 1)  
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.fridayLabel, 3, 4, 1, 1)  

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.mondaySheduleLabel, 4, 0, 2, 1)  
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tuesdaySheduleLabel, 4, 1, 2, 1)  
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.wednesdaySheduleLabel, 4, 2, 2, 1)  
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.thursdaySheduleLabel, 4, 3, 2, 1)  
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.fridaySheduleLabel, 4, 4, 2, 1)        

    def button_clicked(self):
        """ Функция нажатия кнопки """
        # Проверка состояния радиокнопки:
        if self.selected_button:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Информация', f'Выбрана кнопка: {self.selected_button}')
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Нет выбранных кнопок.')

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        self.selected_button = radioButton.text()
        print(f"selected_button -> `{self.selected_button}`")


qss = '''
#centralWidget {
    background-color: rgb(255, 147, 84);
}
QLabel, QRadioButton, QLineEdit, QPushButton {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    font: 24pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";
}
'''
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)                                                    # +++  
    
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("Менеджер расписаний")
    w.resize(1200, 600)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]